# Blazor .NET 8 - Not working when published to Azure App Service on Linux with .NET 8

Tags: azure, blazor, .net-8.0

Created a new .NET 8 Blazor app and managed to run it locally.
Then created a new Web App with service on Linux, selected .Net 8 LTS.

However, application errors when running the published website, with the following detailed log: So how do I upgrade
from:

- preview 7.23375.6
  to:
- 8.0.0-rc.1.23419.4.

[image]

I also tried the Bash commands under advanced tools with this command but it still does not work:

2023-09-29T13:39:47.815649162Z The following frameworks were found:
2023-09-29T13:39:47.815654662Z   8.0.0-preview.7.23375.6 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2023-09-29T13:39:47.815660462Z
2023-09-29T13:39:47.815665362Z Learn more:
2023-09-29T13:39:47.815685063Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
2023-09-29T13:39:47.815690563Z
2023-09-29T13:39:47.815713463Z To install missing framework, download:
2023-09-29T13:39:47.815721164Z https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=8.0.0-rc.1.23419.4&arch=x64&rid=linux-x64&os=debian.12

[image]

however, same error message in logs:
023-09-29T13:44:50.295335014Z The following frameworks were found:
2023-09-29T13:44:50.295355215Z   8.0.0-preview.7.23375.6 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
[image]

Comment: what framework is specified in your csproj? the error tells you that your code was compiled for a framework that is not installed on the server

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Faker.Net" Version="2.0.154" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid" Version="8.0.0-rc.1.23421.29" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: 8.0.0-rc.1.23419.4

Comment: but the azure app service contains 8.0.0-preview 7.23375.6

Comment: try creating a global.json at project root and declare the version 
`{"sdk": {"version": "8.0.0-rc.1.23419.4"}`

Comment: Thank you, I did try that - included a global.json with the specific sdk version, then published to the Azure App Service, however same error persists :

Comment: this is the error in the log stream of the app service: 

The following frameworks were found:
8.0.0-preview.7.23375.6 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Comment: try putting the `8.0.0-preview.7.23375.6` vesrion in the global.json